# How to restrict Docker container logs size to a predefined value

Tags: docker

What is the default log rotation strategy used by `Docker` for container logs.

How I can restrict the docker container log size to be `max 1g` and rotate if the size goes bigger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIU,

Using docker run -
`--log-opt max-size=1g`

using compose -

```
logging:
  options:
    max-size: 1g
```

Also, you can set it globally by updating daemon config, generally `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (Thanks @Stan for suggestion)

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#limitations-of-logging-drivers

Comment: And also you can set that globally for a daemon in daemon config (usually `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in linux boxes)

Comment: thanks , the global thing is working for me and thats what i was looking for

Comment: but what is the default size?

Comment: I guess there is no restriction by default - Ref - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#options

`Defaults to -1 (unlimited).`

Answer (score 1):

This setting in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` worked for my use case:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "1g"
  }
}
```